# How order Ajax call in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, woocommerce-rest-api

I use following codes to get data from a site, I get list of 330 categories. based on woocommerce rest api documentation this endpoint return just first 100 categories, so I have to use `?per_page=` and `&page=` and put it in loop. my problem is that this code is not getting by order, sometimes it get last 30 then rest of 300, or first it get first 100 then 30 then 100 and rest. is this for async control in ajax? how order ajax calls in this loop?

```
for(let i=0; i <= 3; i++){
    var get_cat_data = jQuery.get(url + '/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/?consumer_key=' + ck + '&consumer_secret=' + cs + '&per_page=100&page=' + (i+1));
    get_cat_data.done(function(response_cat){
    console.log(response_cat);
        jQuery.each(response_cat, function(index, value){
            _cat_array.push(value.id + ':' + value.name);
        });
        jQuery('form.submit-new-product-data #form__categories').val(_cat_array);
    });
}
```

Comment: use async/await since jquery ajax calls return something close enough to a Promise

Comment: @JaromandaX how can I do this?

Comment: by using [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: could you please show some codes? I'm newcomer in this concept :)

Comment: there's codes in the links on how to use async/await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code is inside a function, make that function `async` ... then you can do this

```
for (let i=0; i <= 3; i++){
    const response_cat = await jQuery.get(url + '/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/?consumer_key=' + ck + '&consumer_secret=' + cs + '&per_page=100&page=' + (i+1));
    jQuery.each(response_cat, function(index, value){
        _cat_array.push(value.id + ':' + value.name);
    });
    jQuery('form.submit-new-product-data #form__categories').val(_cat_array);
}
```

You can also make the requests in parallel but process them in the correct sequence

```
const promises = [];
for (let i=0; i <= 3; i++) {
    promises.push(jQuery.get(`${url}/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/?consumer_key=${ck}&consumer_secret=${cs}&per_page=100&page=%{i+1}`));
}
const results = await Promise.all(promises);
results.forEach(response_cat => {
    jQuery.each(response_cat, (index, {id, name}) => _cat_array.push(`${id}:${name}`));
}
jQuery('form.submit-new-product-data #form__categories').val(_cat_array);
```

and of course, if your code is not inside a function you could always wrap it in an async IIFE, to enable use of async/await

```
(async () => {
    // your code
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to speed up the ajax responses?

Comment: `await jQuery.get()` always returns done as result? what if the `jQuery.get()` returns error?

Comment: @WebDesign - what happens in your original code? You have no error handling, so I don't either. As for speeding up ajax responses - use the parallel requests code, that's as fast as it gets

Comment: Dear Jaromanda, thanks for solution, I applied first solution, and it works, but for speeding up the process I will check parallel request. Thanks